# Basics on javascript for android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I need to access a site through my app (Webview) .

Now the problem is I can accerss it though thats not exactly my intention . I need the application to automatically click on a button inside the webpage as soon as the user clicks on a button on the android app .

Setting up the android side is pretty well easy , but the point is how do I link the user click to the website click .

What all info do I need to know about this.

As I said , not at all good in javascript ... so will need real good help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can even mention the site if required as well . :)

Answer (score 0):

To call a javascript function from android webview use

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFun()");
```

And make a function in javascript that clicks the button

```
function myFun() {
  var myButton = document.getElementById('myButtonId');
  myButton.click();
}
```

Don't forget to enable javascript on the WebView

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense .

Comment: But the real question is as i said how do i make the javascript for clicking the download button in the "http://keepvid.com/" site .

Is it possible for you to show me on how to create the JS necessary for it ?

FYI - Don't have knowledge in JS .

Comment: Actually who is the owner of this site ? Do you have access to this site ? I mean can you edit the website to include a js file or function ?

Comment: Nope , im not the owner . :( , so if you are the owner only we can do this ?